# How best should I interact with a this <li> from Selenium Java Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to interact with the Nike shoe online shop, login and then select a shoe size from the list and then press add to cart button from Selenium's Java WebDriver:

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-max-2014-running-shoe/pid-830258/pgid-774364

First of all I cannot seem to find the correct `<li>` element and select it - and need some advise on how to do it.

I am finding my code does not work for selecting a shoe size : pastebin.com/6K1RpPKL (as guided by the kind user on the first response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element type in li is not select. Use following code instead, it will work fine.

```
WebElement shoeSizes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'exp-pdp-size-container')]/a"));
shoeSizes.click(); // Expanded
String shoeSize = "8.5";
WebElement shoeSizeSel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='"+shoeSize+"']"));
shoeSizeSel.click(); // Size selected
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='exp-pdp-save-container']/button")).click(); // Added to cart
```

As far as advice goes, you should first learn the basics like identifying elements, using locators before asking these kind of question. Go through these: [Selenium Docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements), [Mozilla Blogs](http://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/). Many such resources are available on web.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should get away from the IDE if you are wanting more robust test-writing like flash.  For your login issue, this is simple.

Using the [getting started with selenium framework](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) your test would look like:

```
@Config(url="http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-max-2014-running-shoe/pid-830258/pgid-774364")
public class NikeTest extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void testNike() {
        click   (By.cssSelector("div.login.nav-section > a"))
        .setText(By.cssSelector("form[name='login-form] input[name='email']"),    "<My Username>")
        .setText(By.cssSelector("form[name='login-form] input[name='password']"), "<My Password>")
        .click  (By.cssSelector("form[name='login-form] button.exp-login-submit")
        
        // now we're logged in.

        // let's select a size of shoe.
        .click  (By.cssSelector("div.exp-pdp-size-and-quantity-container > a.exp-pdp-size-dropdown") // now it's expanded.

        .selectOptionByText(By.cssSelector("select[name='skuAndSize']"), "10.5") // you can replace 10.5 with whatever option you need.
    }
}
```

Those are some CSS selectors you can use.  Also per your Flash thing, i think you're out of luck buddy.. I hadn't heard of any very successful solution with automating flash.

### One key thing here:

Make sure you know what element is receiving the click.  Selenium IDE doesn't do a great job determining WHAT exact element is receiving the click.  My guess is that it was trying either the `<div>` or `<li>` when it's the `<a>` that actually makes the dropdown come down.

Comment: You are a very helpful user! What about the <li> for the shoe size I spoke of earlier. I am aware the IDE is a bad way to do this - but it gives me a starting point when I am new to the API.

Comment: right! I will add to my post.  Also, the getting started with selenium framework that i linked can be very helpful for new users.  If you read the readme in that repo, you'll see why!

Comment: I am finding my code does not work for selecting a shoe size :http://pastebin.com/6K1RpPKL